# Can we use thread pool to support hits from muliple users?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Thread pools can be used to control the number of threads being created and we can execute parallel tasks using threads from the pool.

I have a situation where multiple users are going to hit the application for data. Is there a way I can use thread pool to create a certain number of threads beforehand and provide each thread for execution for a particular user?

Comment: Yes, you can. You wouldn't really be guaranteed that a thread will serve one user only.

Comment: Sounds like the answer is obviously yes. But isn't your application already running in some kind of container that would already manage a thread pool for you?

Comment: Java has Executors.newCachedThreadPool and Executors.newFixedThreadPool exactly for such scenarios, weight their pros and cons and utilise them.

Comment: the answer is yes, you can see the detail here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: you can do like this:

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
Future<String> future = executorService.submit(() -> "Hello World");
// some operations
String result = future.get();

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Yes its running in a container. When a user sends a request for data I'm planning to use a separate thread to serve this as the data retrieval takes long time. Invoking individual threads for every hit looked costly so I thought of moving to thread pools

Comment: @AnanthiGopal Then yes, you can use an executor service for that. As observed by others, you need to be careful with context-related information on your threads (particularly important if you rely on container-managed sessions or similar services).

Comment: @IrfanNasim I would need one ExecutorService to handle the actions for all logged-on users. Where would the service be declared at?  Is there a way of using this Executor Service commonly for all users?